# Looking for an inexpensive NAS that turns off when idle

Tags: raid, nas, storage

I have both Linux and Windows computers on my network and would like a central file store for music and such. What I want is something I can plug an RJ-45 cable into and access from any computer. I would prefer something that doesn't use a proprietary file system, but am interested in any ideas.

My main concern is that the NAS turn off the drive or drives when idle. I would only have it being accessed a small amount of the time. I also would like something with 2 bays that supports RAID 0. And I would like it to be under $200 if possible, at least under $400. This is of course with no drives installed.

I am interested in any that have bittorrent clients, but it is not required.

Comment: Retagged per: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11543/superuser-tags-nas-vs-network-attached-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind building the software side yourself, you could use the [sheevaplug](http://www.plugcomputer.org/), attach drives via USB, and use software RAID. You'll just need to choose enclosures that support power down then.

Comment: It looks like this comes with Linux installed and I would need to merely change config files once a drive is plugged in, is this correct? It may be slightly more power use than I would prefer, but is attractive.

Comment: You'd need to install samba or something but basically yeah.

Answer (score 2):

I believe my Apple Time Capsule router/wap/NAS combo spins down. The 500GB version is under your price point. Performance may not be what you wish however. the 1TB version is currently overpriced, that will probably change in the fall; you can upgrade yourself but it's a pain.

You can also attach external USB drives (Multiple with a hub): I have not tried that.

You could also use an AirPort Extreme (sub $200) with an external USB drive, I believe it will provide windows sharing as well. I have no experience with it however.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but the Time Capsule supports Samba style file sharing for Windows and Linux? I tend to not like Apple products a whole lot (price is a big issue), but if it's not priced too badly, and works that way, I will have to look into it.